# expression of non-boolean type

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Using this statement:

```
select * from qvalues where rowid ,name,compound in (
    select rowid,name,compound from qvalues where rowid in (select rowid from batchinfo where instrument='tf1')
    group by rowid,name,compound
    having COUNT(*)>1 
    )
    group by rowid,name,compound
having rid=min(rid)
```

This error occurs:

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.
>   Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group'.

What is wrong with this SQL statement? I need to find all the occurrences of those three fields in the table `having min(rid)`.

**Update**
Using this query, the outer select is not working. What am I doing wrong?

```
select * from qvalues where rid not in (
select q.rowid, q.name, q.compound, min(q.rid)
    from qvalues q
        inner join batchinfo b
            on q.rowid = b.rowid
                and b.instrument = 'tf1'
    group by q.rowid, q.name, q.compound
    having count(*) > 1)
```

Comment: SQL Server you say? And where is line 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is equivalent to what you're trying to achieve.

```
select min(q.rid)
    from qvalues q
        inner join batchinfo b
            on q.rowid = b.rowid
                and b.instrument = 'tf1'
    group by q.rowid, q.name, q.compound
    having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: @joe thank you so much for your help. i have added another slight level of complexity can youhelp please?

Comment: if multiple batchinfo rows for a given qvalues row then you'll get multiple rows bollixing u phaving count(*)

Comment: @herrow: If you're going to say `where rid not in (...` then the inner query should be modified to return only the one column `min(q.rid)`.

Comment: @joe thank u very much, how would i delete all RID's that are NOT min(q.rid) from the system, and conversely how would i keep ONLY the max(rid) ?

Answer (score 1):

The final `having min(rid)` needs to have comparison

Saying that, there is no associated GROUP BY which you can see if you rearrange your code snippet

```
select * from qvalues
where rowid ,name,compound in (
               select rowid,name,compound from qvalues
               where rowid in (select rowid from batchinfo where instrument='tf1')
               group by rowid,name,compound
               having COUNT(*)>1 
               )
--missing group by
having min(rid) -- > foo
```

Edit: reformulated:

```
select
   *
from
    (
    select
       rowid,name,compound, min(q.rid) as minrid
    from
       qvalues q
    where
       EXISTS (SELECT * FROM batchinfo b where b.instrument='tf1' AND b.rowid = q.rowid)
    group by
        rowid,name,compound
    having
        COUNT(*)>1
    ) foo
    JOIN
    qvalues q2 On foo.rowid = q.rowid AND foo.name = q.name AND foo.compound = q.compound
                   AND foo.minrid = q2.rid
```

And your original error probably comes from a lack of alias of the derived table, coupled with the fact that SQL Server does not support multi-column IN. I use EXISTS not JOIN because you may get more rows from qvalues JOIN batchinfo than you expect (based on Joe's answer)

Comment: @gbn Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near 'foo'.

Comment: @herrow: I had a missing ) on the EXISTS clause

Comment: @gbn Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
The multi-part identifier "q.rowid" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
The multi-part identifier "q.name" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
The multi-part identifier "q.compound" could not be bound.

Comment: @herrow: the aliases are wrong in the last JOIN. Should be "q2". You are allowed to think for yourself: I can't test your code.