# delete rows that do not have min(rid)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

```
select min(q.rid)
    from qvalues q
        inner join batchinfo b
            on q.rowid = b.rowid
                and b.instrument = 'tf1'
    group by q.rowid, q.name, q.compound
    having count(*) > 1
```

1. instead of selecting the min(rid) how do i delete everything except for min(rid)?
2. how do i delete everything except for max(rid)?

please note that i want to delete only values that have the same rowid, name, and compound

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443451/expression-of-non-boolean-type/4443497#4443497)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
begin transaction

delete from [table]
where rid != 
(select min(q.rid)
from qvalues q
    inner join batchinfo b
        on q.rowid = b.rowid
            and b.instrument = 'tf1'
group by q.rowid, q.name, q.compound
having count(*) > 1)
and rowid != 
(select q.rowid
from qvalues q
    inner join batchinfo b
        on q.rowid = b.rowid
            and b.instrument = 'tf1'
group by q.rowid, q.name, q.compound
having count(*) > 1)
and name != 
(select q.name
from qvalues q
    inner join batchinfo b
        on q.rowid = b.rowid
            and b.instrument = 'tf1'
group by q.rowid, q.name, q.compound
having count(*) > 1)
and compound != 
(select q.compound
from qvalues q
    inner join batchinfo b
        on q.rowid = b.rowid
            and b.instrument = 'tf1'
group by q.rowid, q.name, q.compound
having count(*) > 1)
```

to delete all but max, you do the same with the max syntax

Comment: @ramy thank u but please note that i want to delete only values that have the same rowid, name, and compound as in this set

Comment: also, i added a begin transaction at the beginning in case you're actually using this on some production DB. If it ends up being to your liking, use "commit" at the end. otherwise use "rollback"

Comment: @ramy this is the query from gehinnom

Comment: it becomes much simpler if you don't check anything after rowid. the other checks are implied so you don't need to use them

Comment: ...meaning my original query works just as well as this more convoluted one.

Comment: uh...i'm not jewish. but...thanks?  gehinnom is also the arabic word for hell.